# Close Powerpoint Format Shape Pane from VSTO Addin

Tags: powerpoint, vsto

I need to programmatically close the "Format Shape" task pane on the right hand side of the Powerpoint window from a VSTO addin.

I can open and close my own "Custom" task pane.

I have read the VSTO documentation and
searched the Powerpoint Object model for properties/methods in the API, but can find no way of programatically closing Microsoft default task panes in Powerpoint.

Is this even possible?